# Remove glass top from a TO can packaged VCSEL

Tags: packages, laser-diode, disassembly

I have a VCSEL packaged in a TO-46 can ([image here](http://www.ondax.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/TOCanDiode_800px.jpg) / [datasheet with package dimensions](http://www.roithner-laser.com/datasheets/ld_div/rlt8505mg.pdf)). I need to remove the glass top – with or without the silver-coloured cylinder – without damaging the laser diode itself or any electrical contacts within the package. What would be the best method to achieve this?

Comment: Most likely magic. Do you have many to experiment?

Comment: If you mean equipment, I have most standard lab tools and a microscope available. If you mean magic, I'm afraid I do not.

Comment: I meant many of those diodes. I personally would try chopping up the can with a mill or so. But only if I see a reason to do so, which here I do not ;)

Comment: I only have one piece to experiment on, I'd rather not touch the other. The reason is that I want to minimize any kind of optical feedback into the active region and chopping it up is arguably a little extreme of a measure.

Comment: I've taken the top off broken ones.  I think I used a Dremel tool with the thin grinding wheel.  I took it off near where the silver can meets the gold colored base.

Comment: Hi op, I smell a bit of an [XY problem cooking up](http://xyproblem.info). Can you explain *why* you want to do this?

Comment: So you want to minimize the crosstalk, to improve the contrast?

Comment: Basically I want to see whether the so called polarization switching occurs if I minimize the optical feedback into the VCSEL. The slightest feedback can change the polarization dynamics drastically, according to several papers I have read.

Comment: Polarization switching (and other kinds of mode hops) is highly feedback-dependent...but the glass lid is probably AR coated and/or angled to minimize the feedback it produces (assuming the device is meant to be used in applications where hops would be a problem). The optics you use to couple the laser output to a fiber or detector are equally or more likely to be causing a problem.

Comment: As far as I know, the VCSEL has no "internal" polarization stabilizing mechanism, therefore I doubt they put in any more effort to avoid switching. Of course my hopes that switching would occur by increasing the current (after the disassembly) are not too high, but I want to give it a go. I do not couple the output to fiber as of now, the light directly reaches a PBS cube (I know I should collimate it first), then lensed photodiodes detect it in both directions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not used it, but Thor Labs sells a [tool](https://www.thorlabs.com/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=1830) for exactly this purpose.

[image]

It supposedly works for cans with diameters between 2 and 24 mm.

Note that for a VCSEL there is no "rear facet", so the feedback to the monitor photodiode may depend on a reflection off the can's window. If you remove the can, it may no longer possible to use the photodiode to maintain constant power operation.

Comment: I must have missed this one, since I frequently browse their site. The photodiode is not of much interest as for now, but thank you for pointing it out.